# Is the limit $x \to - \infty$ of the cumulative distribution function always equal to $0$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I've the probability density function:

$$
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} x^2 \, e^{-x} & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

The CDF is:

$$
CDF_X(x) = 1 - \left( \frac{x^2}{2} + x + 1 \right) \, e^{-x}
$$

Now if I want to check the goodness of the CDF I should check the limits for $x \to \pm \infty$; the limit for $x \to + \infty$ is 1 and that's ok. But the limit for $x \to - \infty$ is $- \infty$.

Maybe in this case I should consider the fact that $f_X(x)$ is non zero for $x \geq 0$ so I should consider the limit for $x \to 0$ (in this case the result is $0$ which is correct)?

Comment: Note that for $x\to\infty$, you should be using the bottom equation of PDF.

Comment: The cumulative distribution function equals zero for all $x\le 0$ even if that is not explicitly stated.  $F_x(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) \ dt.$  In this case since $f(t) = 0$ when $t<0, F_x(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) \ dt = 0$ when $x<0$

Comment: Hello @MostafaAyaz thank you a lot for the comment

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, distribution functions must have these properties:

1. $\lim_{t\to \infty }F(t)=1$
2. $\lim_{t\to-\infty}F(t)=0$
3. $F$ must be right continuous and increasing

In your case, you have that

$$
\begin{align*}
F_X(c)&=\int_{(-\infty ,c]}f_X(t)\,d t\\
&=\int_{(-\infty ,c]}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty )}(t)\frac1{2}t^2 e^{-t}\,d t\\
&=\int_{[0,c]}\frac1{2}t^2 e^{-t}\,d t\\
&=\left(1-e^{-c}\left(\frac{c^2}{2}+c+1\right)\right)\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty )}(c)
\end{align*}
$$